# How to stop my jupyter notebook to print the color ansi code with the variable output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using `Jupyter notebook v2023.8.1002501831` with `VsCode v1.82.2`.

Every time I attribute a value to a variable, the default output of a variable also prints the ANSI colors:

[image]

I want the output of `color` to be the same as `print(color)`.

How to do that?

(It was working, and 'suddenly' started this behaviour).

Comment: I have the same version numbers and cannot reproduce the issue. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Please also show what version of the jupyter/ipython package you have installed with pip. I have jupyter 1.0.0 and ipython 8.11.0

Comment: This looks weird, there seems to be an extra blank line in the middle of your output. Also this works without issue on my machine (same version). Maybe you can provide more information about the settings, show your *settings.json*, etc.

Comment: thank you for the help guys! I installed all my packages from a previous version, and it worked.

Comment: what packages did you have that didn't work, and what did you change them to that did work?

Comment: Okay. I found a solution, but I didn't keep track of it. I kept my Jupyter and VsCode with same versions as posted, and right now it is running with `jupyter 1.0.0`, `ipython 8.12` and `ipykernel 6.22.0`. However, I can't describe the versions of these packages when I had the problem. If this comment is a good answer, I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution, but I didn't keep track of it.

I kept my Jupyter and VsCode with same versions as posted, and right now it is running with `jupyter 1.0.0`, `ipython 8.12` and `ipykernel 6.22.0`.

However, I can't describe the versions of these packages when I had the problem, because I did not track it.